# Can't remove a user from a group

Tags: groups

When I list the groups I'm in, it says `web`. But when I try leave this group, it says I'm not in...

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the output of `id axiol` for further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like web is that users **initial login group**, axiol and www-data are his **supplementary groups**. See [man usermod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) for more information.

You must change his initial login group

```
usermod -g axiol axiol
```

and if he is enlisted in axiol twice after that, as his initial login group and supplementary group, you might need to fix that afterwards.

```
usermod -G www-data
```

And for the result:

- `groups` displays the groups of the current process
- `groups axiol` displays the groups of the user axiol

So use `groups axiol` and you should see that you had been removed of that group. See `man groups`:

```
Print  group  memberships  for  each  USERNAME  or, 
if no USERNAME is specified, for the current process
(which may differ if the groups database has changed).
```

Comment: I already tried this. `usermod -g axiol axiol` return me a `usermod: no changes`...

Comment: What does `grep axiol /etc/group` and `grep axiol /etc/passwd | cut -f1,3,4 -d:` return?

Comment: Or just use `id axiol` :-)

Comment: In order, here what I have : `www-data:x:33:axiol,maune  axiol:x:1000:axiol`, `axiol:1000:1000`, `uid=1000(axiol) gid=1000(axiol) groups=1000(axiol),33(www-data)`. Seems like it's just `groups` which has a little bug...

Comment: `man group` states that it will print the groups of the current process.. so you need to call `groups axiol`.